# initialize array with default constructor

Tags: c#, arrays

Can I initialize an array of classes with an default constructor (or even better, an specified one) without going through a loop?

So, let's say I have an array of `Person`:

```
var arr = new Person[10];
```

Now, I should initialize each `Person` by looping through all of them.

```
foreach(var p in arr)
    p = new Person();
```

Can I avoid the loop?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839470/array-initialization-with-default-constructor) from @JonSkeet

Comment: Note that your loop wouldn't compile, but we take your point. (Assigning to the loop variable won't work, you'd need a 'for' loop or something equivalent.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an arbitrary sized array, you really can't avoid the loop. You can do something like this:

```
Enumerable.Range(0,10).Select(i=>new Person()).ToArray();
```

but that uses a loop underneat as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = new Person[] {new Person(),new Person()...};
```

Comment: For medium to big arrays, this look even worse than a loop honestly.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault not contesting that, the question was how to avoid the loop.