# Correct way to initialize object in array of objects so that i don't get null pointer references?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I am receiving a null pointer exception, and I narrowed it down to this small block of code. I think it is because when I set `teamStats[iterator].median = Statistics.median` that it can't because it isn't initialized yet. Though I don't know the proper way to initialize an array of objects or the memory ramifications that this code will cause.

Below is the majority of the code i am dealing with besides the class describing `TeamStat`, but I've used all of its members below and they are `public double`.

```
        TeamStat[] teamStats = new TeamStat[DistCount+1];
        int iterator = 0;
        foreach (int i in TeamIDlist)
        {
            var p = userList.Where(x => x.TeamId.Equals(i)).Select(y => (double)y.BS).ToArray();

            var statistics = new DescriptiveStatistics(p);
            teamStats[iterator].median = Statistics.Median(p);

            teamStats[iterator].largestElement = statistics.Maximum;
            teamStats[iterator].smallestElement = statistics.Minimum;
            teamStats[iterator].mean = statistics.Mean;
            teamStats[iterator].variance = statistics.Variance;
            teamStats[iterator].stdDev = statistics.StandardDeviation;
            iterator++;
        }
```

**Update**

Is this the correct way to do this:

```
            TeamStat[] teamStats = new TeamStat[DistCount];
        int iterator = 0;
        foreach (int i in TeamIDlist)
        {
            //Added these two lines
            TeamStat temp = new TeamStat();
            teamStats[iterator] = temp;


            var p = userList.Where(x => x.TeamId.Equals(i)).Select(y => (double)y.BS).ToArray();

            var statistics = new DescriptiveStatistics(p);
            teamStats[iterator].median = Statistics.Median(p);

            teamStats[iterator].largestElement = statistics.Maximum;
            teamStats[iterator].smallestElement = statistics.Minimum;
            teamStats[iterator].mean = statistics.Mean;
            teamStats[iterator].variance = statistics.Variance;
            teamStats[iterator].stdDev = statistics.StandardDeviation;
            iterator++;
        }
```

Comment: You can put it in one line (`teamStats[iterator] = new TeamStat();`), but, yes, that's the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
TeamStat[] teamStats = new TeamStat[DistCount+1];
```

you initialize the array. At this moment, the array contains `DistCount + 1` `null` entries.

If you want the array to contain `DistCount + 1` new `TeamStat` entries, you need to initialize them in a loop:

```
TeamStat[] teamStats = new TeamStat[DistCount+1];
for (var i = 0; i < DistCount + 1; i++)
    teamStats[i] = new TeamStat();
```

Comment: That's just what i got in the end. I didn't know if it was a bad way of doing it though. Thank you.

Comment: @schumacherj: It's the correct way. There is no built-in way to automatically initialize an array of objects, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4839470/87698) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has 2 issues
1) Each object in Array needs to be initialized before accseing its properties
  teamStats[iterator] = new TeamStat();
2) You need to make sure you initizliaed array with same/more capacity as you are trying to assign values to.(TeamIDlist < DistCount+1), otheriwse it will throw index out of range exception.